# Unsigned types break going from Compose 1.0.0-beta06 to 1.1.0-beta02?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I've just tentatively tried switching to the latest Compose version, and my app no longer builds because all unsigned types are now giving "cannot be resolved" errors.

I'm on Kotlin 1.4.32. The types are showing up as fine in Android Studio, it's just at compile time that they're flagged as errors.

It's easy enough to stick with 1.0.0-beta06 for the moment, but is this something I can fix by doing something I've missed at my end, or is this something that's gone undetected through alpha and needs to be reported? Is anyone successfully using unsigned types with 1.1.0-beta02?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong version of Kotlin. Upgrade to this in your project's build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.1.0-beta02'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31'
    }
}
```

And update your app's build.gradle. You should also be using Java 11:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
        useIR = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
        kotlinCompilerVersion '1.5.31'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Note to anyone else who has a similar problem, there were other dependencies that were pointing to fixed, old, versions of libraries leading to app crashes- so everything in the dependencies block needs to be confirmed as up to date. Luckily Android Studio highlights old ones and lets you fix them, I just hadn't twigged what the green highlights meant.